# Define Mount Point in GKE for Cloud Filestore

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-filestore

I have create a Cloud filestore instance with the file share name = gkefs01.

Filestore (gkefs01) is mounted onto a vm instance and have copied data to the directory: /fs01/data

/fs01/data resides on the filestore and holds the dataset.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: fileserver
spec:
 capacity:
   storage: storage
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 nfs:
   path: /gkefs01
   server: 10.0.0.1

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: fileserver-claim
spec:
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 storageClassName: ""
 volumeName: fileserver
 resources:
   requests:
     storage: storage

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: my-pod
spec:
 containers:
 - name: container01
   image: image01
   volumeMounts:
   - mountPath: /c01/data
     name: mypvc
 volumes:
 - name: mypvc
   persistentVolumeClaim:
     claimName: fileserver-claim
     readOnly: false
```

I wanted to mount container01's /c01/data to gkefs01's /fs01/data. How can i do it?

Comment: In the `volumeMounts:` section of the pod spec that uses the corresponding PersistentVolumeClaim.  Do you have a matching PVC and a matching Pod or Deployment or StatefulSet?

Comment: Apologies. My question is not clear and I have updated it

Comment: What happen when you try to create this pod? Any errors?